# go get doesn't works

Tags: go

I tried to install revel framework using the command `go get github.com/revel/revel` throws the following error:

```
error: "..\..\go\src\github.com\revel\log15\handler.go:11:2: no Go files in C:\Users\Mihai\go\src\gopkg.in\stack.v0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel`

> **Here**: https://revel.github.io/

Please do follow the quick start guide from the link above.